# DialogFlow (API.AI) REST with php

Tags: php, rest, symfony, dialogflow-es

I work on DialogFlow recently and I need to send a POST to my own web services.
It's a Rest services work with Symfony et PHP.

So I tried something and it didn't work. 
In the tutorial it worked with Google Cloud, but I don't want to work with it.

I changed the URL of Webhook with my own. I didn't change anything else in DialogFlow because it was good with google. There it is :

```
/**
 * @Rest\View()
 * @Rest\Post("/testDialogBot")
 */
public function testDialogBotAction( Request $request )
{
    $re = "Test reponse";
    $response = new Response(json_encode( array( "speech" => $re, "displayText" => $re )));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;

}
```

The JSON of DialogFlow return :

```
"status": {
  "code": 206,
  "errorType": "partial_content",
  "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout."
},
```

I'm sure it can work, I do something bad probably.

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that's fine, you don't need every parameters. My URL was wrong and It seems that DialogFlow doesn't accept https but only http.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response) the response "should" have the following fields: speech, displayText, data, contextOut adn source. You are only sending speech and displayText. Maybe adding the others will do the trick.

Also, the limits stated on the docs for the response are:

> Timeout for service response – 5 seconds.   Data received in the
>   response from the service – up to 64K.

Check if your server can send the response within those parameters